# How to convert a python script that requires imported modules into an executable file in Windows

Tags: windows-7, exe, python-3.5, pyinstaller, spyder

I'm trying to write a program on Windows 7 Professional that will make predictions based on user inputs. This program is meant to be used by other users, who do not have python installed on their computers.

In order to do this I have written a GUI script in Spyder using Python 3.5.6. I can execute the code fine and the GUI works great, however, when I try to convert it into an executable file that other people can use using pyinstaller, it hangs.

I'm quite certain that this is due to the import of external modules such as numpy and keras in the script.

If I exclude the modules, the executable file is made, however, it does not work as it doesn't have the needed modules in order to function.

I have provided a very simple example script below, as I cannot reproduce my actual code here due to it being proprietary.

I wrote a separate script in which I import all necessary modules, thinking this might help but it did not. The list of modules are included below, excluding custom scripts.

numpy
pandas
sklearn
keras
tkinter

## simple example

## The following setup.py file and command work, making a simple exe that can be run by users without having to install python:

```
# setup.py:
input('Press ENTER to begin.')
num1 = float(input('Number 1  '))
num2 = float(input('Number 2  '))

print([num1,num2])
input('Press ENTER to exit.')

# Command in IPython Console of Spyder
!pyinstaller setup.py --onefile
```

## The following setup.py file and command do not work, instead it hangs and no error msg is received:

```
# setup.py:
import numpy as np
input('Press ENTER to begin.')
num1 = float(input('Number 1  '))
num2 = float(input('Number 2  '))

print(np.array([num1,num2]))
input('Press ENTER to exit.')

# Command in IPython Console of Spyder
!pyinstaller setup.py --onefile
```

## The following setup.py file and command do make an exe, however, it closes as soon as it opens because it requires numpy to properly function:

```
# setup.py:
import numpy as np
input('Press ENTER to begin.')
num1 = float(input('Number 1  '))
num2 = float(input('Number 2  '))

print(np.array([num1,num2]))
input('Press ENTER to exit.')

# Command in IPython Console of Spyder
!pyinstaller setup.py --onefile --exclude-module numpy
```

I'm really at a loss and am not sure what to do. I've looked through documentation and previous questions and have not found anything to be useful, and the suggestions did not fix the problem, whatever it may be.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cx_freeze()` module to convert you python file to **exe**.